# How do I identify my window manufacturer?

Tags: windows

My windows have "**K M C**" stamped on the aluminum separator plate sandwiched between the 2 panes of glass. **Who is the manufacturer?** I need to buy replacement parts.

Responses to follow up questions by other users:
Pittsburgh, PA. USA

Yes, I googled "K M C".

These are old, cheap a$$ windows. The KMC is followed by 79 probably indicating 1979. I think they may be TRACO brand, which was bought by Kawneer, which subsequently went bust around 2018.

As a tip for others, spare traco windows parts can be found at:

1. window hardware direct, co.:
   https://windowhardwaredirect.com/
2. Amazon. Search for "traco window parts"

Follow up questions:

1. Does anyone have **any tips for squaring an aluminum window frame**, that was poorly installed into an un-square opening 30 years ago, LOL? (not shims were used) I think its hopeless and a waste of time, but thought I would ask.
2. **Any tips for shimming aluminum windows which have U-shaped frames** facing the window openings? (seems most, if not all aluminum/vinyl windows are constructed like this) So basically, only the inside window edge and outside window edge contact the window opening (the visible portion where you would add the caulking). Adding a block of wood to fill the U-channel to pad the center of the U-channel to the edge dimension is easy before installation. After the window is installed, installing this wood fill to the channel is much more difficult.

Comment: Windows are commonly made local. Where are you located?

Comment: Also, did you Google KMC windows? If you did, top result for me: https://www.kmcwindows.com/

Comment: Not necessarily true, @UnhandledExcepSean. Ever hear of Pella, Anderson, Jeld-Wen, etc.? National companies that produce windows in a few factories and ship 'em everywhere. Of course, if you were to find one of those names on the window, you'd know...

Comment: The glass unit is often made by a different company than the window manufacturer. You need to find clues on the sashes and window frames.

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read through the [help] a bit. You'll find that _answers_ don't belong in the _question_ here, nor do "follow up" questions. Please feel free to ask a new question - nobody here will look down on you for doing so. Also, please [edit] out the "answer" part and put it down there in the box labeled "your answer" - self answers are appreciated and accepted here.